# How to store varargs in a List or an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, variadic-functions

```
   public Spectacle(String title, String... Interpretes) {
        this.title = title;
        for(String str : Interpretes) {
            this.Interpretes=new ArrayList<String>(Interpretes.length);
            this.Interpretes.add(str);

    }
    }
```

When using this code then iterating through an entryset where I added my Spectacle object, I only retrieve one value, example:

```
Spectacle s = new Spectacle("My title","title1", "title2", "title3");

//puting the object in a hashmap
//creating an iterator


Entry<Integer, Spectacle> entry = itr.next();
                 System.out.println("value = " + entry.getValue());
```

This would only retrieve title3

Comment: Varargs are simply an array. So ask yourself: how would I turn an array into a list? And hint: your code is almost correct, but you should move the **creation** of that list in front of the loop. You keep creating a new list per element, add one element ... and throw away the previous entries that way.

Comment: `this.Interpretes=new ArrayList<>(Interpretes.length);` should be moved before the for loop. Then it should work ;)